# Can RAID 1 fail (me)?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

I read about RAID 25 years ago but never used it.  Now I am considering mirroring a Dell work laptop's SSD using its BIOS/chipset RAID.  Let's assume monthly backups are performed but I am looking to "protect" the data created between those backups.

I'd like to understand the failure state: If a drive can no longer save a byte in a certain location, will this be detected/protected by the RAID (how)?  And, how will I be informed of this?

Comment: RAID1 can definitely fail. But also consider that both disks are probably managed through the same (single) controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can RAID 1 fail?
Yes, but having 2 drives 100% fail at the same time is rare.  Having the exact same sector on both drives fail is also rare, but again it can happen.

As chris davis points out, the stress of copying the whole drive onto a new drive is a valid concern. You definitely need to replace at least 1 drive proactively every couple years.  RAID 6 is the better choice.

> If a drive can no longer save a byte in a certain location, will this
> be detected/protected by the RAID (how)?

How:
So the hard drives have checksums and ECC data for each sector.
The data is read from a sector, and compared against the checksum.  Everything matches read is successful and nothing to see here.

However, if they don't match then the ECC or error correction algorithm is used to correct the failed bits in the sector.  These failures are usually logged in the SMART data.  This works up to a point, if there are too many bad bits to fix, then the sector is marked BAD.  Again this is usually recorded in the SMART database.

The biggest problem/concern is the RAID controller is free to check the SMART data or ignore it.  It is impossible to know which without doing a deep dive on the exact controller your using.

Now the RAID controller could ask both disks to read the same sectors, if the data read doesn't match then it knows it has a problem.  However, different RAID controllers have different implementation.

SMART sometimes also monitors ECC corrections, and when the drive is new there should be 0, and the number should increase very slowly.  However, eventually as the drive wears out the number will sky rocket into the millions or billions, and its time to replace the drive.  Even a 100,000 is too many.

Now, back to backing up in between backups.

For that I have crashplan, it is a cloud based solution that immediately uploads any changed files to the cloud.  It doesn't backup windows itself, just all the files your working on.  Click Save in any application and crashplan goes to work upload the files.  I know other companies exist that do the same thing, but I don't know there names.

Comment: "_having 2 drives 100% fail at the same time is rare_" - multiple or cascading failure is definitely a problem with larger arrays. One disk fails, so you replace it. But then the act of reading the entirety of the remaining working disk to replicate to the new replacement stresses it to the point that it too fails. For example, RAID5 is no longer considered "safe"

Comment: cybernard, So, a byte save is confirmed by either the RAID controller and/or a SMART implementation?  (I would have thought the hard drive firmware would be initially responsible and then report it to the RAID.)  And on this machine, the BIOS' SMART and RAID seem to have separate enabling toggle switches, so I assume one does not need the other.(?)  Importantly, I'd also like to know how/when I find out about this failure.

Comment: It depends on the RAID controllers some can do email alerts, some are dumb and don't report anything at all.  You may have to download something to monitor the SMART data yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> If a drive can no longer save a byte in a certain location

This will typically handled by the drive itself, whether it's part of an array or not, though the mechanism of [sector reallocation](https://www.disktuna.com/sector-reallocation-on-hard-drives-explained/). It depends on the RAID controller I suppose how many sector reallocations it will deem acceptable. I have had controllers that didn't allow for even a single reallocated sector.

Now let's assume the opposite, then a read error will be returned by the drive and so the RAID controller will know about it and the OS will know about it. It then depends on the RAID controller how it will handle this and if it will for example declare the RAID degraded or something. On read error a sector will not be automatically reallocated.